# Create Windows SBS 2008 User Account without Email

Tags: exchange, windows-sbs-2008, accounts

Just today I've been handed an SBS 2008 server to do some maintenance on. I've never used SBS 2008 before today, so this is a real noob question:

Is it possible to create a user account without creating an associated exchange mailbox? I've been asked to create a new user, but not give them an email address.

I guess I could just disable their email account in Exchange, but is there a nicer method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can setup a user without an email, but you will need to do so by going into active directory users and computers and running the add user wizard in here. The SBS add user Wizard always creates an Exchange mailbox, where as the ADUC wizard allows you to uncheck the box to create an Exchange mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new user account in the third step the assistant would ask you if you want to create an email account for the user, you simply have to uncheck the option and no mailbox will be created

Comment: +1, because SBS 2008 flags each user entry in AD with a special attribute so it can be seen in the SBS console.  You can, of course, use ADUC, but you lose the use of the console for that user and probably make things harder for the next SBS admin to work on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

This must be done in Active Directory. The SBS 2008 Console pulls user information from Exchange, so creating a user there creates an Exchange mailbox and email address.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create the user with the email, then go into Exchange Management Console->Recipeint Configuration->Mailbox, right click on the newly created user and disable their mailbox.

When you go back to the SBS Users Console and refresh you'll see that this user doesn't have an email address.